# How could i make a mirrored (sync) hard link copy of files from different folders on windows?

Tags: windows, sync, symbolic-link, mirroring, hardlink

I'm trying to create hard link entries from a folders content into another folder, but synced in such a way that any files deleted from one (or the target) will be deleted from the other.
There is one caveat tough and is that the source folder is comprised of way too many sub-folders, with the files nested in then; My aim are said files mirrored into a single folder.

im used to link shell extension and its smart mirror is exactly what im looking for, however it can only target folders (not their contents), which would mirror all the sub-folders inside which im trying to get rid of...

Sadly no other symlinks will do for me. To give some context the files are part of an 'database' that is generated by an app as directories, and it creates a folder for every single file (every folder contain the main file and a sidecar, `.json`) and it's huge.
I want to access those files in a practical manner with a number of other applications - none of which handled symbolic links well, but work fine with hard links.

Given the sizes involved and my available space a mirrored copy is out of the question - so my hopes are with hard links.

Any ideas how may I achieve this? Any software that can make this?

Comment: Just delete all of the links and recreate them every now and then?  That will get rid of any that have been removed from the source directory.

Comment: hm... that can work, definetly i will have to do it as a last resort if theres no other way. I would prefer 2 way sync so it would all update and be cleaned no matter where i deleted, but i can just adjust to just deleting files in the source via the app... at least the files would be modifiable anywhere(thanks to hard linking). That could be it!